# How to make .docx files open in Pages by default

Tags: ms-office, pages, launch-services

Is there a way to make .docx (Word) files open in Pages by default? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark/highlight the file with the mouse/pointer and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

In the *Open with:* part choose *Pages* and then hit the button *Change All…*.

[image: file info window]

---

After compiling and installing *[duti](https://sourceforge.net/projects/duti/files/)* this can also be done from the [command line](https://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/09/19/changing-default-applications-on-a-mac-using-the-command-line-then-a-shell-script/).